# GWT in eclipse on os X complie fails when upgrading to new version of GWT

Tags: eclipse, macos, gwt, upgrade

When I upgrade to the newest version of GWT, I get the following error when I try to compile my code.

```
Compiling module com.blah
   [ERROR] Errors in 'file://Path/To/GWT/src/client/CatalogTabs.java'
   [ERROR]  Internal compiler error
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JEnumType, but class was expected
at com.google.gwt.uibinder.attributeparsers.EnumAttributeParser.<init>(EnumAttributeParser.java:35)
at com.google.gwt.uibinder.attributeparsers.AttributeParsers.<init>(AttributeParsers.java:88)
at com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderWriter.<init>(UiBinderWriter.java:271)
at com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator.generateOnce(UiBinderGenerator.java:135)
at com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator.generate(UiBinderGenerator.java:119)
at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generate(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:48)
at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generateIncrementally(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:60)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:662)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:74)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:259)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.doFindAdditionalTypesUsingRebinds(WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.java:106)
at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.process(AbstractCompiler.java:254)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:444)
at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:175)
at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:288)
at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.access$400(AbstractCompiler.java:145)
at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:632)
at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.BasicWebModeCompiler.getCompilationUnitDeclarations(BasicWebModeCompiler.java:124)
at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.getCompilationUnitDeclarations(WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.java:54)
at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:517)
at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:35)
at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:541)
at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:495)
at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:407)
at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:215)
at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:187)
at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:159)
at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:87)
at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:81)
at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:166)
```

If I create a new project and copy all my code etc, the build will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure but there was a change in the gwt compiler from 2.1 to 2.2 I think, which makes it necessary to recompile all used gwt libraries with the newer compiler.

If you have dependencies which generate code at compile time (many do), take a look at this post from a google dev: http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/3cdbe1bcd6966957

Comment: I had the problem when i went from 2.1 to 2.2 AND when i went from 2.2 to 2.3.

Comment: do you mean libraries that depend on my project, or libs that my project depends on?

Comment: libs that your project depends on